# Add Product Attribute to CMS page

Tags: product-attribute, cms, ce-1.9.0.1

Using 1.9.0.1 rwd

Hi,
I am trying without any success to add details from a product attribute to a CMS page. Basically I want to be able to select a product (say via its id number) and the display a selected attribute from that product (say short description) and then display it in a CMS page along with what ever else is on that page. I have seen lots of ways to create and add categories such as “featured Products” but none for a individual product. The products are all simple and not configurable etc. if that makes a difference?

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here is the short version.
Create a template file like this.

`app/design/frontend/{theme}/{package}/template/cms/product_attribute.phtml`

```
<?php 
$id = $this->getProductId();
$attribute = $this->getProductAttribute();
if ($id && $attribute) {
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($id);
    if ($product) {
        $attributeRawValue = $product->getData($attribute);
        $attributeValue = $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($product, $attributeRawValue, $attribute)
    }
    else {
        $attributeValue = '';
    }
}
echo $attributeValue;
```

Now you should be able to use this template inside a cms page like this.
Add this to the content of the cms page:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="cms/product_attribute.phtml" product_id="YOUR PRODUCT ID HERE" product_attribute="YOUR PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE CODE HERE"}}
```

This is the quick and dirty way of doing it. IN theory you should not use `load` in templates. All your logic should go in a block. But in order to have a block class you need to create a module and that take more time and more code.

I haven't tested the code so watch out for syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks Marius, but i cant get it to work. No errors it just dosnt dispaly anything in that area of the CMS Page i have put it. Not sure what to look for or what i may have done wrong..

Comment: Make sure that you added a custom template "product_attribute.phtml" in your theme.